# Error running a fork that has a scoped package

Tags: node.js, cypress, git-fork

I am running a cypress fork that has the @packages scope. I don't have a scoped package for my organization, and simply want to use this fork for development. How can I get around the error "Cannot find module '@packages/...". I tried changing @packages to ~packages but this didn't work. I'm not sure if this is the problem but I am not able to get cypress to create a folder in appdata nor in node_modules/.bin.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I shouldn't have changed anything. The key is in this link, basically using yarn to do everything. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/CONTRIBUTING.md#getting-started